# rpm/yum/dnf one (or two) liner to determine whether a package needs updating?

Tags: makefile, rpm, yum, dnf

Update: Working code to at least provide some info follows below, based on John Bollinger's answer....

As part of packaging/managing a complex project, I need to determine automagically whether a package needs to be installed or upgraded.

The first part, installation, is easy (example shown in `bash`; I'm using a very short form for illustration: the actual code will be more defensive and informative):

`rpm -q ${package} >& /dev/null || sudo dnf -y install ${package}`

The second part is determining whether or not there are upgrades available. My first thought was to use something like

`dnf info ${package} | grep -q 'Available Packages' && sudo dnf upgrade ${package}`

but that will trigger if there are packages of the same name but with different architectures. (Note that the lack of `-y` here: in case of available upgrades, human review may be required; as per the first example, this is an illustrative example, the actual implementation would like involve separate confirmation.)

I may not have a choice but to do some complex text and version and architecture processing, but I'd like to a) leverage what others have done and b) make this as KISS and reliable as possible.

In case it's relevant, the overall motivation is primarily efficiency and partly DRY: The checks will go into Makefile prerequisites and/or recipes. I'm considering having something like a `check` target that will query whether or not to apply available upgrades, and I'd that check to be as KISS and reliable as possible. For example, I might have something like this:

```
upgradables=()
for package in ${packages}; do
    if someEfficientCheck $package; then
        upgradables+=($package)
    fi
done
cat << EOM
    The following packages are upgradable:

        ${upgradables[@]}

EOM
read -p 'Updgrade these? ' answer
case $answer in...
etc.
```

Many thanks!

UPDATE: WORKING CODE

The following at least tells me more or less reliably what the state of a given package is. I need to find an example of a package that will return multiple architectures, e.g., to weed things down a bit more....

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 
package=$1
[[ -z $package ]] && { printf "\n\tA package name is required.\n"; exit 1; }
     
isInstalled=no
isUpgradable=no
     
rpm -q ${package} >& /dev/null && isInstalled=yes
if [[ $isInstalled == "yes" ]]; then
    arch=$(rpm -q --queryformat "%{ARCH}" ${package} 2> /dev/null)
    dnf info ${package}.${arch} | grep -q 'Available Packages' && isUpgradable=yes
fi
     
[[ $isInstalled == "yes" ]] && echo "'${package}' is installed"
[[ $isUpgradable == "yes" ]] && echo "'${package}' is upgradable"
```

I'm not crazy about calling `rpm` twice, but I can live with it (I'm working on a compact statement to get both the return value and the output value). The next step will be wrapping that to query the list I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

> My first thought was to use [`dnf info`] but that will trigger if
> there are packages of the same name but with different architectures.

DNF and Yum understand package specifications of the form <package>.<arch>, so you can say, for example,

```
dnf info my_package.x86_64 | grep -q '^Available Packages' && do_something
```

to avoid DNF reporting about packages for architectures other than the one you are interested in.

Of course, that requires you to *know* what architecture you're interested in, which is not necessarily straightforward.  Some tools that may be helpful there include:

- the `uname -m` command
- (for packages that are already installed) the output of `rpm -q <package>`, perhaps with use of `-qf` to specify a custom query format that makes the output contain more information and / or be easier to consume

Do not overlook noarch packages, whose existence means that you always have to accommodate at least two package architectures.  Moreover, don't overlook that on a multilib system it might not be just that the same package is available for multiple architectures, but that it is *installed* for multiple architectures.

However, I'm inclined to be skeptical of the whole idea. Especially anything involving user interaction in a makefile smells bad to me, but more generally, if you're committed to (trying to) upgrade to the most recent versions of a set of packages, then I'd be inclined to just run the upgrade command instead of checking first.  On the other hand, being committed to upgrading to the latest version also smells bad -- it makes sense to ensure that you satisfy at least some set of *minimum* requirements, but I'm having trouble seeing the justification for at all times demanding the latest available version of the packages of interest.

And if it would suffice to ensure at least a minimum version of one or more packages, then you might find that the `yum-builddep` command solves a lot of problems for you.  Especially so if the context is building RPMs, but you could make broader use of `yum-builddep`, too, as long as you're willing to write enough of an RPM .spec file to be accepted by the tool and to convey the build requirements.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that's got me down at least a somewhat useful path. I share a couple of the concerns you express therein, re user interaction in makefiles, upgrading just because, etc. Ultimately, what I want is a fairly reliable KISS way of informing (at least) myself that more investigation is required. I've thrown some working code into my original post, it's got more-or-less the right smell.